# Let $V=\mathbb{Z}^2$ and let $L$ be the submodule of $V$ spanned by the columns of $A=\begin{bmatrix} 6 & 4 \\8 & 12 \end{bmatrix}$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=\mathbb{Z}^2$ and let $L$ be the submodule of $V$ spanned by the columns of $A=\begin{bmatrix} 6 & 4 \\8 & 12 \end{bmatrix}$. Find a basis $(\overrightarrow{\alpha_1}, \overrightarrow{\alpha_2})$ of $V$ and integers $c_1,c_2$ so that $c_1\overrightarrow{\alpha_1}$, $c_2\overrightarrow{\alpha_2}$ is a basis for $L$.

So I find that the characteristic polynomial for this matrix is $x^2-18x+40$. Hence it's roots are $x=9\pm \sqrt{41}$.

So my first question is: Can you have a submodule of rationals in a module over the integers?

If so, then I start to find the eigenvectors
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 3\pm \sqrt{41} & -4 \\ -8 & -3\pm \sqrt{41} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & -4 \\ -8 & -3 \end{bmatrix} \pm \sqrt{41} \cdot I
$$
Since the since term in the sum is a linear combination of the basis in $\mathbb{Z}$, I disregarded it and try to find the eigenvector using the first term.

(Is this correct?)

Comment: Why are you trying to find the eigenvalues of $A$? For your other question: yes, you can have a submodule of rations in a module over the integers (let the module be $\mathbb{Q}$?). I suspect you meant to ask something else, and if so, please phrase your question more clearly.

Comment: Then how do I find the basis for $L$?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform elementary column operations:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 6 & 4 \\8 & 12 \end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 \\-4 & 12 \end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\-4 & 20 \end{bmatrix}
$$
Compare this with
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\-2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
whose columns are a basis for $V$.